# Classloader in JVM

Tags: java, classloader

This is an example using classloader and you can see the output. Why are `obj`'s and `obj2`'s classloaders different? I know about the 'delegate to parent classloader' idea.

```
public class jvm_77{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ClassLoader myLoader = new ClassLoader(){

            public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException{
                try
                {
                    String fileName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".")+1)+".class";
                    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
                    if(is == null)
                    {
                        return super.loadClass(name);
                    }
                    byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
                    is.read(b);
                    return defineClass(name,b,0,b.length);
                }catch(IOException e)
                {
                    throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
                }
            }

        };

        Object obj = myLoader.loadClass("Chapter7_ClassLoader.jvm_77").newInstance();
        jvm_77 obj2 = new jvm_77();

        System.out.println(obj.getClass().getClassLoader()); //Chapter7_ClassLoader.jvm_77$1@1888759
        System.out.println(obj2.getClass().getClassLoader()); //sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@45a877

        System.out.println(obj.equals(obj2));//false
        System.out.println(obj instanceof Chapter7_ClassLoader.jvm_77);//false
        System.out.println(obj2 instanceof Chapter7_ClassLoader.jvm_77);//true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why obj's classloader and obj2's classloader are different?

This line is creating an instance of the `jvm_77` class that was loaded by the standard classloader.

```
jvm_77 obj2 = new jvm_77();
```

This line is creating an instance of the `jvm_77` class that was located by your custom classloader.

```
Object obj = myLoader.loadClass("Chapter7_ClassLoader.jvm_77").newInstance();
```

So basically, what you are asking is why the two approaches don't give you the same `Class` object.  And the answer to that is in the way that you have implemented `loadClass` in you classloader:

- The default behaviour for a `loadClass` method is:

  1. Try the parent classloader
  2. If that fails, check if we've already loaded the class
  3. If that fails, find the resource and load the class.
- Your classloader's `loadClass` method does this:

  1. Attempt to find resource
  2. If the resource find succeeds, load the resource
  3. If the resource find fails, try the parent classloader.

Clearly, your custom classloader is going to *attempt* to define a new class ... if possible.  And apparently, it is succeeding.

---

In short, the classloaders are different in the output because of the way you implemented the `loadClass` method.